# Confusion on how to use select() in TCP

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, system-calls

In

```
int select(int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds,
           struct timeval *timeout);
```

`readfds` & `writefds` - Can they be used simuntanouesly? EX: If i have a read operation and a send operation one after the other

Also, can anybody provide a good link or sample program?

Is `select(...)` used only in a server program? or only in TCP ?

Comment: I don't understand 'simultaneously'. You can select on a socket for both readability and writability at the same time, if that's what you mean, but you don't need to wait for writability to write anything. You should just write, and use the writability part of select to deal with the occasional case where `send()` returns -1 with `errno = EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.`

Comment: That's what i wanted to know. I tried using it in my program but wasn't getting the desired programs. Then I glanced at some programs on the net which had some of the fields set to NULL. So i began wondering whether select() has to be called separately for a recv and send operation, with the other fields set to NULL, that is writefds for send and readfds for recv

Comment: Also, I have another question,  on this site http://www.cse.sc.edu/~wyxu/515Fall08/slides/select.pdf, it was mentioned that select()   will provide the functionality : Return when
Any of the descriptors in the set {1,4,5} are
ready for reading
Any of the descriptors in the set {2,7} are
ready for writing
Any of the descriptors in the set {1,4} have an
exception condition pending  .

Comment: What does this imply? In the sense what does this set represent? If it's a set of descriptors, then how are the numbers assigned? What if the no. of descriptors are lesser than 7?   . The extract is from the 5th slide of the 3rd sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_isset):

> Three independent sets of file descriptors are watched. Those listed
>   in readfds will be watched to see if characters become available for
>   reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in
>   particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file), those in
>   writefds will be watched to see if a write will not block, and those
>   in exceptfds will be watched for exceptions. On exit, the sets are
>   modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed
>   status. Each of the three file descriptor sets may be specified as
>   NULL if no file descriptors are to be watched for the corresponding
>   class of events.

Small example providing `readfds`:

```
fd_set set;

FD_SET(0,&set); //stdin
FD_SET(socket,&set); //socket may be your tcp-fd where you wanna read from

while(1) {

select(socket,&set,NULL,NULL,NULL) 

FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(0,&set);
FD_SET(socket,&set);

if(FD_ISSET(0,&set)) 
{
 //write the input on the stream
}

if(FD_ISSET(socket,&set)) 
{
 //read any content from the stream

}
}
```

Just declare a set of `writefds`, and check their states with `FD_ISSET` and it should work *simuntanouesly*.

`Select()` can be used everywhere where you wanna process multiple descriptors.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sorry for the delay in my response. It certainly cleared the cloud over some significant issues. I have one pending doubt, however. Can you post a link to a snippet which shows how it handles multiple readfds and writefds,that would just further illustrate your point on how select() assigns and uses multiple file descriptors in sets {1,4,5} , {2,7} and {1,4}